# How can I test superagent promises using Jasmine?

Tags: ecmascript-6, jasmine, vue.js, superagent

I'm using VueJS 2.0 with SuperAgent in order to create an API client connector. I'm working on test coverage for my API and having trouble when it comes to test SuperAgent methods itself. I need to know how to spy on my private methods within superagent requests:

This is what my SuperAgent request looks so far:

```
// Importing superagent as request
import request from 'superagent';

if (['get', 'head'].includes(method)) {
  return request[method](this.Url(path, opts))
  .set(getHeader())
  .query(params)
  .then(handleSuccess, handleError);
}

return request[method](this.Url(path, opts))
.set(getHeader())
.query(params)
.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
```

This is inside a conditional because, otherwise, if the HTTP method is not GET or HEAD, the query(params) won't be passed (since it's not needed in this case).

Question 1: How can I spy on superagent in order to know if my promise returned a successful response? Even though I'm not using superagent's promise (since I'm using then() instead of end()), I still need to spy on superagent request;

Question 2: How can check if the query() method has been called by superagent instance (request)?

Test case 1 (using Jasmine):

```
it('should set the query params if the method IS "get" or "head"');
```

Test case 2:

```
it('should call the success callback if the response code is between 200 and 299');
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check `superagent-mock` for example. Or you can stub `request` methods directly and return mocked object (it should have the same method chains as real superagent object). I wouldn't recommend to spy on real requests.